# How to use URL Re-Write with Query String

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a URL re-write with a query string but my problem is the URL re-write does not work when I try to use the query string.  The URL re-write works fine when I use it without the query sting.  I have searched online and did exactly what they said but I was still getting an error.  So let me show you what works first which is without the query-string:

This is what I have in the Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup

      RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForCustomer", "MyTest", "~/Users/MyOldPage.aspx");
    }
```

Everything works fine if I run the code above. 
So I have tried now to pass query-string in the URL and this what I have done that does not work so far:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup

      RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForCustomer", "MyTest/{My_ID}", "~/Users/MyOldPage.aspx");
    }
```

And the code behind for MyOldPage.aspx I have this code but not sure if it is even necessary but this is what I saw online when I was researching:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myquerystring = Page.RouteData.Values["My_ID"] as string;
```

Comment: Any reason this is tagged "asp-classic?"

Comment: asp.net? asp classic? make up your mind.

Comment: sorry maybe i selected the wrong thing.  it should be only ASP.Net